# Can't upload phone gap to app store - Error itms-90035 - Xcode

Tags: xcode, cordova, itunes

I'm well aware that there many similar question in SO to similar issues, but none of the solution helped, and also the error msg I get is different
[image]

Background: i've been submitting successfully many apps before (with much struggle...), my MAC crashed and I've reinstalled it.

I had to revoke my Distribution Certificate, I've downloaded and install the new certificate.

I've created a new app, and a new App Id + Distribution Provision certificate.

Download and install in xcode

In Build Settings > Code Signing I choose the Distribution Provision certificate i've created and downloaded.

One strange thing is that it shows 'iphone distribution' while it was normally showing 'IOS distribution'

Other than this all goes smoothly but than when I submit to app store it gets stuck for 10 minuets and than I get this error.

Please help...

NOTEs:

1. in other thread the error specified a specific file, the error I get doesn't specified any file
2. the solution in other thread was to delete .sh files from target, I don't have any .sh in my target.
   I tried to delete other files that seems to be not needed from the target - it didn't help

Edit:

I tried to recreate everything from scratch - I delete all keys/certificates from key chain, I've revoked Distribution certificates, created a new App Id, create a new Provisioning profile, created a new App in itune.

Edit:
I updated my Cordoba and Xcode,
I created a new Cordova app from scratch,
Upload it to itune - upload successful!!!

I copied the www dir from my original project to the new project - receive the previous itms-90035 error

So there is some files in the www folder that causing this, but how can I find out which of my hundreds is causing this? other than trying to upload every possible sub-group of these files - which will take about a year.

Comment: I have the same problem. The former test release of the app (Ionic Framework) loaded without problems. The new release (which should be public available) gives exactly your error, without pointing to a specific file.

Comment: Marco Pallante, please update on any progress u make on this. it is a complete show stopper for us.

Comment: yes I will, but I have no clue on what to try to solve it. It is a stopper for me too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an old build.sh file in my www (from ancient phonegap time), deleted it and WALLA - problem solved.

Comment: This answer put me on the right route: an extraneous file inside the build directory.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any `.sh` file in my `www` directory, maybe because I didn't used PhoneGap, but directly started with Cordova.

At the end, I solved my issue, too, even if I'm not sure about how.

My app had some errors related to Cordova plugins; I noticed was that some Cordova variables were always undefined, and that was because I put the

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

tag inside the

```
<!-- build:js dist_js/app.js -->
...
<!-- endbuild -->
```

block of the `gulp-useref` concatenation. That script was not in the source directory, so it wasn't included in the `dist_js/app.js` file and so the application didn't loaded it, causing the problems with Cordova plugins and undefined variables.

But it was put into the destination directory by the build process, together with the Cordova plugins.

I think that those files, included in the App but not used by it, were causing the signature error from iTunes Connect, in a way similar to your `build.sh`: a script that is copied in the App by the build process, but the App doesn't use.

My final thought about this error is that, when happens, you should search for executable files (Javascript, Bash, or others) that belongs to the build, but that are not used.

However, please understand that I have no real evidence for my conclusion. I should do some test, but I have no time at the moment.